# jQuery selector for facebook Iframe

Tags: jquery, facebook

This is my first question. I'm using the FacebookLikeBox in a site I'm working on, and i want to display a contact form to every user who click on the Like button, but i don't know how to select the `.liketext` or the `.connect_widget_like_button`. Both are inside the iframe that creates the facebook div. I've tried to get it like this:

```
$("iframe").contents().find(".liketext")
```

but doesn't work. Can't get the iframe id because it's dynamic, so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You got the answer on how to proceed already, so just FYI: You __can not__ access iframe content that is loaded from a different domain with JavaScript – it’s called __Same Origin Policy__, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

Just "listen" for the button press and do something once its clicked:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    // like clicked
});
```

Comment: Just to add: the list of Facebook JS SDK events you can subscribe to is in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/